# Thesis template - LyX

Tags: lyx, thesis

I have two questions and I cannot find a solution up to now:

1. I open a predifined template from thesis (i.e. `chapter-1.lyx`) and all the mathematical equations that I insert with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> are aligned left. How can I have a centered alignment?
2. In `thesis.lyx`, how can I add a new chapter? Only `chapter1` and `chapter2` are predefined but what to do if I want to insert another `chapter3` from external file?

Comment: On the very first line of the preamble where the document class is stated you will probably find "fleqno" in the straight options brackets. This option will left-align equations in the document. Remove this option to have your equations centre-aligned.

Comment: :( i don't see something like this to preamble!

Comment: As i see it uses only \userpackage{calc}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The thesis template that is included with LyX uses left-aligned equations by default, by having `fleqn` among the options to the document class. To fix this, go to Document --> Settings --> Document class, and remove `fleqn` from the *Custom*  text box.
2. Create a new `.lyx` file, similar to the existing one. You can for example make a copy of one of the first two chapter-files, and rename it to e.g. `chapter-3.lyx`. To include this new chapter in the same way as the first two,

   1. Insert --> Branch --> Insert new branch.
   2. Insert --> File --> Child document. Use *Include*  as *Include Type*, and choose your new chapter file, `chapter-3.lyx`.

Comment: It doesn't let me to remove it, but i change it to fceqn and is ok now