# Equations numbers are in the left side

Tags: numbering, lyx

How do I change the equation numbering to appear in the right, instead of the left default side in Lyx?

Comment: I know that the default is suppse to be the right side but it's not like that for me. I already tried even to reinstall Lyx..

Comment: Try adding the `reqno` option to the `\documentclass` command.

Comment: Are you using the included thesis template? That has `fleqn` added to the document class by default, which does this, remove it and you should be fine (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/thesis-template-lyx/119007#119007).

Answer (score 2):

You must be loading a package that provides this numbering alignment as the default option. You can pass packages to the document class which should override the options. Under Document > Settings... > Document Class add the custom option `reqno`:

[image]

Note that the settings may not be adequately reflecting the visual representation in LyX.